# Cython Cimport unresolved external symbol

Tags: python, cython

My setup.py are :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

extensions = [
    Extension('_hmmc', ['_hmmc.pyx'], include_dirs = [np.get_include()]),
    ]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
    )
```

and I'm experimenting with cimport to get it to work.

```
from numpy.math cimport expl

import numpy as np
print(expl(5-2))
```

However, the erros are

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _npy_expl

Any idea? I have checked that my cython/includes/numpy/math.pxd had this:

> long double expl "npy_expl"(long double x)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to keep it simple, one could use `exp` from the standard library, otherwise there are some hoops to jump through, to get it work with `npy_expl`.

The usual Numpy-API is header-only (more precisely, only headers are needed at compile-/linktime, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58155766/5769463)), but this is not the case with math-functions. There is define [`NPY_INLINE_MATH`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1bf2b9434b74a27019a04622dd5bc3790102e7d6/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_math.h#L19), which would also present numpy's math library as inline functions, but this will not work on installed numpy-distributionen, because those lack the `core/src`-folder, where the definitions of math-functions are given.

So you have to add the precompiled [static numpy's math library](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1bf2b9434b74a27019a04622dd5bc3790102e7d6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c) to your setup. It can be found in folder `core/lib` and is called (at least on linux) `libnpymath.a`.

The most robust way is to use `get_info` from `numpy.distutils.misc_util`, which returns a dictionary providing values for `'define_macros'`,
 `'include_dirs'`, `'libraries'` and `'library_dirs'` - i.e. values we need to pass to Extension, e.g.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

from numpy.distutils.misc_util import get_info
npymath_info = get_info('npymath')

extensions = [
    Extension('_hmmc', ['_hmmc.pyx'],
               **npymath_info 
               ),
    ]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
    )
```

---

There is also the function `get_mathlibs` from `numpy.distutils.misc_util` but it only works if `_numpyconfig.h` is present, which is not the case at least in my installation.